# C# WPF load and use custom controls from DLL during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, runtime

I'm new to WPF and also not yet a professional to C#, however, I'm creating an application which has to get a group of true/false states and creates toggle switches for each one and then set its (isChecked) property.

however after about 3 hours googling I found this code so I can use external control in the WPF during the run time and edit it as a control, not as a toggle switch :-

```
            Control Switch = null;
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/CTS.dll");
            Type[] tlist = asm.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type t in tlist)
            {
                if (t.Name == "HorizontalToggleSwitch")
                {
                    Switch = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Control;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Switch.Name = "MasterSwich" + i;
            Switch.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            Switch.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 35, 0);
            Switch.Width = 100;
            Switch.Height = 35;

            SwichesPanel.Children.Add(Switch);
```

That works fine but I can't set any property (like IsChecked) related to the toggle switch as it considers it a control only.

how can I fix this or if there is any better idea of importing a control from DLL file during runtime ?

The toggle switch file in case anyone needs it can be found here : [Toggle Switch Demo](http://toggleswitch.codeplex.com)

---

### **Update:-**

I can declare `HorizontalToggleSwitch` when I add `Using ToggleSwitch;` but I recive a nice error saying

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ToggleSwitch, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8637099990568f75' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

any ideas ?

Comment: Just cast it to `HorizontalToggleSwitch`.

Comment: example please ?

Comment: In your code just declare `HorizontalToggleSwitch Switch = null;` and when instantiating it do `Switch = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as HorizontalToggleSwitch;`

Comment: I couldn't do this before but i figured out that I need to import it at using, I did and it worked but when I try to perform the process I get that error :-

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ToggleSwitch, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8637099990568f75' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I just imported the lib as mentioned in the **Update** and used process manager to find out what was the compiler looking for and figured out that it want an exact file name for the DLL so just setting everything again it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone having the same issue! Here is my solution.
I do not know why Windows is struggling with this, but if you use the Assembly only in xaml Windows cannot find it, or searches in the wrong folder. In my case i was working in an AddIn-Folder and **not** in the

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

The Addin aka Windows was able to find all the assemblies when used in C# code, but when i used the ToggleSwitch UI element only in xaml code, it was searching in the wrong folders, not the addin folder.

**I solved this issue with the following.**

at the addin startup function i added a pseudocode to force the app to load the assembly, so that in later use it will be available

```
  static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            ...
            LoadLoadUiAssemblies();
            ...
        }

        public void LoadUiAssemblies()
        {
            // somehow the loading of the wpf components does not work, 
            //here we load the assembly in the cache so that we can use it
            var ts = new WPFToggleSwitch.ToggleSwitch();
        }
    }
```

here is the usage in the WPF

```
<UserControl x:Class="ViewManager.DimensionAssistantView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewManager"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:p="clr-namespace:ViewManager.Properties"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"

             xmlns:wts="clr-namespace:WPFToggleSwitch;assembly=WPFToggleSwitch"

             Name="balalal"
             MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100">


 <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     IsEnabled="{Binding IsFaceSelected}" Background="WhiteSmoke">

            <wts:ToggleSwitch IsChecked="{Binding  SelectedFaceSketchsVisibleStatus}" CheckedText="un-visible" UncheckedText="Visible">
                <wts:ToggleSwitch.Content>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{x:Static p:Resources.DAShowAllDimensionsToggleButtonText}" />
                </wts:ToggleSwitch.Content>
            </wts:ToggleSwitch>
        </StackPanel>
```